# XSLT sort subelement followup

Tags: xslt, sorting

Similar to the previous subelement sort, but I have a few extra layers of nodes. I can't figure out a simple extension to the previous answer that works.
[How to sort a subelement of XML with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572854/how-to-sort-a-subelement-of-xml-with-xslt)

The simplified input example:

```
<Iteration>
  <Iteration_query-ID>NODE_10008</Iteration_query-ID>
  <Iteration_query-def>NODE_10008</Iteration_query-def>
  <Iteration_query-len>339</Iteration_query-len>
  <Iteration_hits>
    <Hit>
      <Hit_id>110679166</Hit_id>
      <Hit_def>[Roseobacter litoralis Och 149]</Hit_def>
      <Hit_len>68</Hit_len>
      <Hit_hsps>
        <Hsp>
          <Hsp_score>300.0</Hsp_score>
          <Hsp_evalue>4.94413E-26</Hsp_evalue>
          <Hsp_query-from>69</Hsp_query-from>
          <Hsp_query-to>272</Hsp_query-to>
        </Hsp>
      </Hit_hsps>
    </Hit>
    <Hit>
      <Hit_id>114767284</Hit_id>
      <Hit_def>[Roseovarius sp. HTCC2601]</Hit_def>
      <Hit_len>68</Hit_len>
      <Hit_hsps>
        <Hsp>
          <Hsp_bit-score>127.487</Hsp_bit-score>
          <Hsp_score>319.0</Hsp_score>
          <Hsp_evalue>3.0968E-28</Hsp_evalue>
          <Hsp_query-from>69</Hsp_query-from>
          <Hsp_query-to>272</Hsp_query-to>
        </Hsp>
      </Hit_hsps>
    </Hit>
  </Iteration_hits>
</Iteration>
```

I want to sort by one of the Hsp attributes, such as Hsp_score. I've been able to get it to sort, but I can't figure out how to keep it from dropping out some of the Hit nodes:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">

    <xsl:import href="identity.xsl"/>

    <!--
    Iteration/Iteration_hits/Hit/Hit_hsps/Hsp
    -->
    <xsl:template match="Iteration_hits">
        <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="Hit/Hit_hsps/Hsp">
                <xsl:sort select="Hsp_score" order="descending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

Would this work?

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Hit">
    <xsl:sort select="Hit_hsps/Hsp/Hsp_score" order="descending"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Answer (score 2):

**There is a *slight* problem with David's code**:

As written, 120 will come *after* 90, although the sort order is specified as `descending`.

The proper way to sort with numeric sort keys is illustrated below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<!--                                                    --> 
    <xsl:param name="pNewType" select="'myNewType'"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
<!--                                                    -->
    <xsl:template match="Iteration_hits">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Hit">
                <xsl:sort select="Hit_hsps/Hsp/Hsp_score"  
                 data-type="number"
                 order="descending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied on this XML document:

```
<Iteration>
    <Iteration_query-ID>NODE_10008</Iteration_query-ID>
    <Iteration_query-def>NODE_10008</Iteration_query-def>
    <Iteration_query-len>339</Iteration_query-len>
    <Iteration_hits>
        <Hit>
            <Hit_id>110679166</Hit_id>
            <Hit_def>[Roseobacter litoralis Och 149]</Hit_def>
            <Hit_len>68</Hit_len>
            <Hit_hsps>
                <Hsp>
                    <Hsp_score>120.0</Hsp_score>
                    <Hsp_evalue>4.94413E-26</Hsp_evalue>
                    <Hsp_query-from>69</Hsp_query-from>
                    <Hsp_query-to>272</Hsp_query-to>
                </Hsp>
            </Hit_hsps>
        </Hit>
        <Hit>
            <Hit_id>114767284</Hit_id>
            <Hit_def>[Roseovarius sp. HTCC2601]</Hit_def>
            <Hit_len>68</Hit_len>
            <Hit_hsps>
                <Hsp>
                    <Hsp_bit-score>127.487</Hsp_bit-score>
                    <Hsp_score>90.0</Hsp_score>
                    <Hsp_evalue>3.0968E-28</Hsp_evalue>
                    <Hsp_query-from>69</Hsp_query-from>
                    <Hsp_query-to>272</Hsp_query-to>
                </Hsp>
            </Hit_hsps>
        </Hit>
    </Iteration_hits>
</Iteration>
```

**the correct result is produced**:

```
<Iteration>
    <Iteration_query-ID>NODE_10008</Iteration_query-ID>
    <Iteration_query-def>NODE_10008</Iteration_query-def>
    <Iteration_query-len>339</Iteration_query-len>
    <Iteration_hits><Hit>
            <Hit_id>110679166</Hit_id>
            <Hit_def>[Roseobacter litoralis Och 149]</Hit_def>
            <Hit_len>68</Hit_len>
            <Hit_hsps>
                <Hsp>
                    <Hsp_score>120.0</Hsp_score>
                    <Hsp_evalue>4.94413E-26</Hsp_evalue>
                    <Hsp_query-from>69</Hsp_query-from>
                    <Hsp_query-to>272</Hsp_query-to>
                </Hsp>
            </Hit_hsps>
        </Hit><Hit>
            <Hit_id>114767284</Hit_id>
            <Hit_def>[Roseovarius sp. HTCC2601]</Hit_def>
            <Hit_len>68</Hit_len>
            <Hit_hsps>
                <Hsp>
                    <Hsp_bit-score>127.487</Hsp_bit-score>
                    <Hsp_score>90.0</Hsp_score>
                    <Hsp_evalue>3.0968E-28</Hsp_evalue>
                    <Hsp_query-from>69</Hsp_query-from>
                    <Hsp_query-to>272</Hsp_query-to>
                </Hsp>
            </Hit_hsps>
        </Hit></Iteration_hits>
</Iteration>
```

**Do note the use of the *`data-type` attribute* of [`xsl:sort`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#sorting).**

Comment: @Jweede this is something important -- not just for show-off. Imagine you find unexpectedly one day the nodes sorted in an unwanted way! BTW your own solution has the same problem.

Comment: I like your answer Dimitre, but that's a lot of reading.  is it possible you can post a concise introduction or summary for it (about the size of the other posts)?

Comment: @Nerdling When one does not know some fundamental stuff, a lot of reading is really needed! 90% of all answers on SO suffer from being untested and incomplete. An answer must provide self-contained working code and demonstrate the results when executed on a specific input. The OPs input is long agr.

Answer (score 1):

Tested David's code.

This will work.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Hit">
    <xsl:sort select="Hit_hsps/Hsp/Hsp_score" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

[W3 documentation agrees.](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_sort.asp)

**EDIT:** Added Dimitre's data-type attribute. Thanks Dimitre!

Comment: make sure to add the data-type="number" attribute to ensure proper ordering.

Comment: @Jweede this is something important -- not just for show-off. Imagine you find unexpectedly one day the nodes sorted in an unwanted way! BTW your own solution has the same problem. And you even didn't up-vote my answer...