# XSLT sorting a part of xml document 

Tags: xslt

I have been working over a requirement where I need to sort a part of the xml document (not the complete tree).

```
<Root>
<AllData>
    <Data_not_to_be_sorted>
        <Additional_data1>
            <Some_test_data1/>
            <Some_test_data2/>
        </Additional_data1>
    </Data_not_to_be_sorted>
    <RealData>
        <Some_data1/>
        <Some_data2/>
        <GrandFather>
            <Data_required_as_it_is></Data_required_as_it_is>
            <Father>
                <Value>4</Value>
                <Name>name in 4</Name>
            </Father>
        </GrandFather>
        <GrandFather>
        <Data_required_as_it_is></Data_required_as_it_is>
            <Father>
                <Value>3</Value>
                <Name>name in 3</Name>
            </Father>
        </GrandFather>
    </RealData>
            <RealData>
        <Some_data1/>
        <Some_data2/>
        <GrandFather>
            <Data_required_as_it_is></Data_required_as_it_is>
            <Father>
                <Value>2</Value>
                <Name>name in 2</Name>
            </Father>
        </GrandFather>
        <GrandFather>
        <Data_required_as_it_is></Data_required_as_it_is>
            <Father>
                <Value>1</Value>
                <Name>name in 1</Name>
            </Father>
        </GrandFather>
    </RealData>

</AllData>
</Root>
```

So after sorting on Father/Value, I should be getting correct sequence of GrandFather

```
<Root>
<AllData>
    <Data_not_to_be_sorted>
        <Additional_data1>
            <Some_test_data1/>
            <Some_test_data2/>
        </Additional_data1>
    </Data_not_to_be_sorted>
    <RealData>
        <Some_data1/>
        <Some_data2/>
        <GrandFather>
            <Data_required_as_it_is></Data_required_as_it_is>
            <Father>
                <Value>3</Value>
                <Name>name in 3</Name>
            </Father>
        </GrandFather>
        <GrandFather>
        <Data_required_as_it_is></Data_required_as_it_is>
            <Father>
                <Value>4</Value>
                <Name>name in 4</Name>
            </Father>
        </GrandFather>
    </RealData>
            <RealData>
        <Some_data1/>
        <Some_data2/>
        <GrandFather>
            <Data_required_as_it_is></Data_required_as_it_is>
            <Father>
                <Value>1</Value>
                <Name>name in 1</Name>
            </Father>
        </GrandFather>
        <GrandFather>
        <Data_required_as_it_is></Data_required_as_it_is>
            <Father>
                <Value>2</Value>
                <Name>name in 2</Name>
            </Father>
        </GrandFather>
    </RealData>

</AllData>
</Root>
```

In other words, I want to sort over sub tree GrandFather based on Father/Value. Rest everything should remain same. I have tried something like below ..but this is just copying the source xml into output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<!-- Template to copy the nodes as they are -->

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="GrandFather">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">    
    <xsl:sort select="self::Father/Value" data-type="number"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: In general, when you say something is "not working" you need to specify how: wouldn't compile? crashed at runtime? unexpected results?

Comment: Actually, not working means, this code is giving me the output as it is ...so I get the output which is same as source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This correct, shorter, simpler and more general transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[F]">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>

   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
    <xsl:sort select="self::F/Value" data-type="number"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to the provided XML document:**

```
<Root>
    <AllData>
        <Data_not_to_be_sorted>
            <Additional_data1>
                <Some_test_data1/>
                <Some_test_data2/>
            </Additional_data1>
        </Data_not_to_be_sorted>
        <data>
            <Some_data1></Some_data1>
            <Some_data2></Some_data2>
            <F>
                <Value>2</Value>
                <Name>name in 2</Name>
            </F>
            <F>
                <Value>1</Value>
                <Name>name in 1</Name>
            </F>
        </data>
        <data>
            <Some_data1></Some_data1>
            <Some_data2></Some_data2>
            <F>
                <Value>4</Value>
                <Name>name 4</Name>
            </F>
            <F>
                <Value>3</Value>
                <Name>name in 3</Name>
            </F>
        </data>
    </AllData>
</Root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<Root>
   <AllData>
      <Data_not_to_be_sorted>
         <Additional_data1>
            <Some_test_data1/>
            <Some_test_data2/>
         </Additional_data1>
      </Data_not_to_be_sorted>
      <data>
         <Some_data1/>
         <Some_data2/>
         <F>
            <Value>1</Value>
            <Name>name in 1</Name>
         </F>
         <F>
            <Value>2</Value>
            <Name>name in 2</Name>
         </F>
      </data>
      <data>
         <Some_data1/>
         <Some_data2/>
         <F>
            <Value>3</Value>
            <Name>name in 3</Name>
         </F>
         <F>
            <Value>4</Value>
            <Name>name 4</Name>
         </F>
      </data>
   </AllData>
</Root>
```

Comment: Hi Dimitre, Thanks for the solution :) ..However my requirement is bit changed ..Now I need to sort the GrandFather on grandchild value ..I am re posting the problem..

Comment: Dimitre, I seen a previous post where you posted a solution. My requirement is similar to that and I am able to write the code as per that post. Thanks for your previous post :). The link I am referring to is - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616387/xslt-sort-subelement-followup

Comment: So my learning from this has been - Whenever we want to sort a particular segment, match the pattern with its parent first and then apply the sort template over the children...Thanks to all of you who replied to my queries.

Comment: @user1375199: I am glad my answers have solved your problem. Would you, please, *accept* this answer -- by clicking on the check-mark next to the answer?

Comment: Dimitre, I have accepted your answer. Thanks...one query ..I am using below code for my requirement --  <xsl:template match="RealData">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="Data_required_as_it_is"></xsl:apply-templates>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="GrandFather">
     <xsl:sort select="Father/Value" data-type="number"/>

 
 </xsl:apply-templates>...........The question is - is there any way so that I can generalize "Data_required_as_it_is" so that everything which is there before "GrandFather" is copied as it is ..actually there are many tags like "Data_required_as_it_is" in my file.

Comment: @user1375199: Comments aren't a good format for code. Please, ask a new question and let me know. I will be glad to have a look.

Comment: I have posted my query on a new link...Please have a look..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482103/xslt-a-generic-rule-in-apply-template-to-include-pattern

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `F/Value` is not a child of `Root`.  Also, applying a sort just under `Root` (if you provided a usable sort key) would sort just the child elements of the root.  You will need to do something like this (untested):

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Some_data1"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Some_data2"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="F">
        <xsl:sort select="Value"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

The key is to remember that the stylesheet is declarative, not procedural.  The XSLT engine reads your XML, and at each input element it looks at the stylesheet to decide what to output.

Comment: thanks a lot, your answer helped me to write the correct code ...Here is the code which is working for this requirement... <xsl:output indent="yes"/> <xsl:template match="@* | node()"> <xsl:copy> <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/> </xsl:copy> </xsl:template> <xsl:template match="data"> <data> <xsl:apply-templates select="Some_data1"/> <xsl:apply-templates select="Some_data2"/> <xsl:apply-templates select="F"> <xsl:sort select="./Value"/> </xsl:apply-templates> </data> </xsl:template> </xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: The only thing I needed to do was to add <data> and </data> tag in your code to make the code working...Thanks a lot :)