# XSLT - A generic rule in apply template to include multiple nodes

Tags: xslt

I am working over sorting the Grand Parent based on a field in Father. The source file looks like

```
<Root>
    <AllData>
        <Data_not_to_be_sorted>
            <Additional_data1>
                <Some_test_data1/>
                <Some_test_data2/>
            </Additional_data1>
        </Data_not_to_be_sorted>
        <RealData>
            <Some_data1/>
            <Some_data2/>
            <GrandFather>
                <Data_required_as_it_is></Data_required_as_it_is>
                    <Father>
                        <Value>4</Value>
                        <Name>name in 4</Name>
                    </Father>
            </GrandFather>
            <GrandFather>
                <Data_required_as_it_is></Data_required_as_it_is>
                <Father>
                    <Value>3</Value>
                    <Name>name in 3</Name>
                </Father>
            </GrandFather>
        </RealData>
        <RealData>
            <Some_data1/>
            <Some_data2/>
            <GrandFather>
                <Data_required_as_it_is></Data_required_as_it_is>
                <Father>
                    <Value>2</Value>
                    <Name>name in 2</Name>
                </Father>
            </GrandFather>
            <GrandFather>
                <Data_required_as_it_is></Data_required_as_it_is>
                <Father>
                    <Value>1</Value>
                    <Name>name in 1</Name>
                </Father>
            </GrandFather>
        </RealData>
    </AllData>
</Root>
```

The XSLT code, I am using is as below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="RealData">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="Data_required_as_it_is"></xsl:apply-templates>
<xsl:apply-templates select="GrandFather">
<xsl:sort select="Father/Value" data-type="number"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>

</xsl:copy>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The code is working well...My query is - Can I write a generic line for

Data_required_as_it_is.  Imagine a situation where I have 20 different xml tags for "Data_required_as_it_is" so either I need write all of them manually or just write them in a generic way...

The output of the code is as below:

```
<Root>
    <AllData>
        <Data_not_to_be_sorted>
            <Additional_data1>
                <Some_test_data1/>
                <Some_test_data2/>
            </Additional_data1>
        </Data_not_to_be_sorted>
        <RealData>
            <Some_data1/>
            <Some_data2/>
            <GrandFather>
                <Data_required_as_it_is></Data_required_as_it_is>
                    <Father>
                        <Value>3</Value>
                        <Name>name in 3</Name>
                    </Father>
            </GrandFather>
            <GrandFather>
                <Data_required_as_it_is></Data_required_as_it_is>
                <Father>
                    <Value>4</Value>
                    <Name>name in 4</Name>
                </Father>
            </GrandFather>
        </RealData>
        <RealData>
            <Some_data1/>
            <Some_data2/>
            <GrandFather>
                <Data_required_as_it_is></Data_required_as_it_is>
                <Father>
                    <Value>1</Value>
                    <Name>name in 1</Name>
                </Father>
            </GrandFather>
            <GrandFather>
                <Data_required_as_it_is></Data_required_as_it_is>
                <Father>
                    <Value>2</Value>
                    <Name>name in 2</Name>
                </Father>
            </GrandFather>
        </RealData>
    </AllData>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:template match="RealData">
>       <xsl:copy>
>           <xsl:apply-templates select="Data_required_as_it_is"></xsl:apply-templates>
>           <xsl:apply-templates select="GrandFather">
>               <xsl:sort select="Father/Value" data-type="number"/>
>           </xsl:apply-templates>
>       </xsl:copy>
>   </xsl:template>
> ```

**One could use a more generic code like this**:

```
<xsl:template match="RealData">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:sort select="self::GrandFather/Father/Value" data-type="number"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**Note**: This will sort any any non-`GrandFather` node before any `GrandFather` node and will do the specified sorting of `GrandFather` elements by their `Father/Value` elements.

In case it is desired that the non-`GrandFather` elements remain interspersed within the `GrandFather` elements, this can also be accomplished -- ask another question if interested.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match anything that isn't a **GrandFather** element at this point, you should be able to do something like this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::GrandFather)]"></xsl:apply-templates>
```

Note that if you had elements after any existing **GrandFather** elements, they would be moved to before the sorted **GrandFather** elements in the output in this case though.

Comment: @Tim, Thanks..This is working...and there are no nodes after GrandFather...but I am just thinking if there are any elements after GrandFather, then order will not remain same...