# Parsing xml using xslt fails when adding namespace to xml

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, transform

I have the following xml file:

```
<DataConfiguration 
  xmlns="http://www.mysite.com/namespace"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mysite.com/namespace/DataConfiguration.xsd">

  <rule>
    <if>
       ...
    </if>
    <then>
       ...
    </then>
  </rule>

</DataConfiguration>
```

which I want to parse using the following xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:doc="http://www.mysite.com/namespace" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsi">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match = "/">

<xsl:for-each select="//rule">
  <xsl:for-each select="if/*">
     ...
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The xslt works as expected but when I add the xmlns attribute to the top element of the xml it fails to find the xml elements. I saw some related questions on this site but still didn't figure out how to solve my specific problem. I tried to add doc: to the select as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401291/xslt-applied-to-xml-doc-with-xmlns-attribute) but it didn't help. Maybe it's because I'm using // ? Any other way to do these queries ?

Any other suggestion how to solve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is the biggest XPath XSLT FAQ. Just search: `"XPath default namespace"`**

**Very briefly**:

Change:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//rule">   
  <xsl:for-each select="if/*">   
     ...   
  </xsl:for-each>   
</xsl:for-each>
```

To:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//doc:rule">   
  <xsl:for-each select="doc:if/*">   
     ...   
  </xsl:for-each>   
</xsl:for-each>
```

**The reason for the observed confusing problem is that in XPath any unprefixed name is considered to be in "no namespace".**

Therefore, `select="//rule"` doesn't select any element in a document that is in a default namespace -- there is no element named `rule` that is in no namespace.

**Instead, the XPath expression must contain prefixed names and the prefix must be associated with the default namespace** -- as done in the above solution.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, it works ! Just to add some more info, I noticed that if I have xpath that contains multiple elements I need to add prefix to each one, for example: <xsl:value-of select="//doc:default/doc:applicationName"/>

Comment: @Tamir: Glad my answer was useful. Please, consider accepting it as the SO established rules dictate (just click on the check-mark next to the answer you wish to accept).