# XSLT sorting - how to sort AND copy the whole input as sorted output

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, xpath, xslt-grouping

I am trying to sort an XML file using XSLT transformation, but it doesn't do what I want. I want to sort the XML lexicographically by the `loc` element.

This is my original XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc>url3</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>url2</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>url1</loc>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

This is the xslt:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"
        version="1.0" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="urlset">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="url">
                <xsl:sort select="loc" data-type="text" order="ascending" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And I'd like to see this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc>url1</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>url2</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>url3</loc>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

I tried to follow this question, but I can't get it working.

[How to sort a subelement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572854/how-to-sort-a-subelement-of-xml-with-xslt)

The XSLT above just copies the original xml without any sorting and that's it. Can somebody help me? How can I sort the `loc` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is not sorting, but selecting/matching nodes that are in their own *namespace*. This template:

```
<xsl:template match="urlset">
```

does not do anything, because the `urlset` element and all its descendants are in the "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" namespace. You need to declare this namespace in your stylesheet, assign it a prefix and use that prefix when addressing the nodes:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:sm="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" version="1.0" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sm:urlset">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="sm:url">
            <xsl:sort select="sm:loc" data-type="text" order="ascending" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been struggling with this for a while. And yes, the problem was the missing namespace! Worked perfectly.